# simplexml_load_file php function sometimes doesn't work using the same xml file

Tags: php, xml

I have a php scripts that parse several xml files using simplexml_load_file. My problem is that sometimes it is working and sometimes not for  **the same xml file**. The function returns false and libxml_get_errors() returns an empty array.
I tried to use simplexml_load_string and file_get_contents functions instead of simplexml_load_file,
but is the same...
(I am using PHP5.6)

Has anyone else experienced this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: The file is on your system or remote? Sounds like file is inaccessible for some reason.

Comment: The php runs on linux server (nginx) and the xml file is on the same machine and loaded using local path ( /local-path/myfile.xml ).

Comment: And function file_exists returns true, so the file is accessible. Also the function get_file_contents returns the content of the file, but  simplexml_load_file or simplexml_load_string sometimes it is working and sometimes not.

Comment: Another remark, the XML document is well formed.

Comment: Does the file content get modified using a somewhat "concurrent" request at some point maybe?

Comment: @CBroe No, I'm testing with my own xml files…